# IPhone quiz game with dynamic questions updated via server (Parse/JSON)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently in the process of developing a quiz game for iOS. The quiz will be split by difficulty (beginner,  intermediate,  and advanced),  each difficulty type will have a set of categories (e.g. Intro to baking,  master baking terms, in the kitchen , history of baking etc) and each category will have a set of questions that are randomised. There will be no set limit to questions per category.

The quiz needs to be setup in a way that an external user can update the contents of the questions,  categories or answers via an online server (e.g Parse)  a scoring system can be developed in Game Center and the server can be called to update stats of the player's progression (point total,  leader boards,  etc)

Another option is to create either a standalone API,  or a website that an external user can use to update quiz questions and answers.  Maybe a JSON file?, using NSData?

In the future,  users will be able to challenge each other to timed quizzes per category, user will be able to earn badges for completing challenge questions,  etc).

What is the most plausible way to go about a project like this? Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good idea. You should probably start quickly.
Refer to Ray Wenderlich article to get insight of backend system: [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more)
And a very good Game Center integration [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12)